# USB target device is busy, how to fix?

Tags: usb, 18.04

How to fix this error in `woeusb`?
This is the error:

> Error: Target device is currently busy, unmount all mounted partitions in target device then try again.
>   Target device is busy,
>   please make sure you unmount all filesystems on target device or shutdown the computer before detaching it.

Does anyone knows how to fix this error?

Comment: That usb is currently being used or open in a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a process `cd`'d to there, or reading/writing there. Use `sudo lsof +D /dev/sdX` (where "`sdX`" is your disk. Also read `man lsof`. Or use `fuser`, part of the `psmisc` package. Read `man fuser`.